# db2 shared libraries location for user defined functions

Tags: db2, shared-libraries, db2-luw

I would like to use a shared library I produced from  db2 queries.

My shared library depends on `boost` that, in my machine, is locate in `/usr/local/lib`.

When I try to run the queries using my functions I got errors: they dosn't work because db2 cannot find boost libraries i.e. cannot resolve the location of the libraries.

How to tell `db2` where to locate the libraries path and which enviromnent variable s I should use?

I tried to ise userprofile and profile.env but without success.

```
 # userprofile
 LIBPATH=/usr/local/lib:LIBPATH

 #profile.env
 DB2ENVLIST='LIBPATH ..other stuf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand your question correctly. You have C or C++ external UDFs that depend on some other libraries. If so, I think you should set the DB2 registry variables, not your environment variables:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LIBPATH  # this must be in the global profile
db2set DB2LIBPATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
db2set DB2ENVLIST="LD_LIBRARY_PATH otherstuff"
```

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable must be set in the environment for the instance owner user and the DB2 fenced user, because the external routines run under one of these two. Probably the best way to do it is to set /etc/profile. This should be done before executing the `db2set` commands.

After setting the registry variables using `db2set` you must restart the DB2 instance (`db2stop force` then `db2start`).

Comment: OK let me recap. I should set LD_LIBRARY_PATH set for a common user (in the .bashrc) and then I need to set thos registry variable. RIght? I don't understand when you say. 1. must be in the global profile: do you mean in /etc/profile or any other file? 2. when you say 'environment of fenced user and instance owned' do you mean their .bashrc or other file in their db2 profile folder?